# How to fix syntax highlighting in examples

Tags: c#, documentation, syntax-highlighting, docfx

I have noticed that in my DocFX output the syntax highlighting is not correct for the examples, meaning example code inside `<example><code>...</code></example>` doc comments, even though the API signatures are highlighted correctly.  It seems that the issue is due to the following difference in the HTML output:

For API signatures, html has something like this:
`<pre><code class="lang-csharp hljs">public void foo()</code></pre>`.

But in the examples it is:
`<pre><code>.....</pre><code>`.

The difference is that `class` attribute in the `code` tag is absent.

When i manually add `class="lang-csharp hljs"` into the `code` tags into the html output of the examples, this fixes the syntax highlighting.

The question is: how can I make DocFX generate correct html output for the examples (with `class="lang-csharp hljs"` present in `code` tags)?

Comment: Did you check the project's github issue tracker for this? I'd consider this a bug (if not configurable somehow) and either file it as such or if I can fix it post a pull request with the fix.

Comment: I've never used DocFX (I'm an author of similar VSdocman), so just a blind guess. The <code> tag has an unofficial optional attribute 'lang'. It's been used for years by various documentation tools. See https://www.helixoft.com/files/vsdocman/help/acodexml.html. You can try <code lang="C#"> to see if it helps.

Comment: I think OP was expecting DocFX to include the language attribute @PeterMacej

Comment: @PeterMacej thanks, i tried lang attribute with several possible values, but unfortunately no change in the generated html.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods I agree this looks like a bug, at least there should be documented attribute to specify language.